# JS error when initializing bootstrap datetimepicker if input value contains only time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I'm using [DateTime Picker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I want to load a only Time picker.

I initialize my input field like this and works good. This let me pick only times [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7x6y95y/):

```html
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_hour1">
  <input type="text" id="hour_from" name="hour_from" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

```js
$('#datetimepicker_hour1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'es',
  format: 'hh:ii',
  minuteStep: 60,
  autoclose: true,
  minView: 1,
  maxView: 1,
  startView: 1
});
```

If I want initialize this input with a time preselected, JS error occurs:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined"

But if I put the input value like this `2017-12-24 13:00`, the input time picker have that full value. That works good, but I want that the first value could be only the time, not full datetime.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2ac1ssw/) with a value preloaded. I want that this value could be `13:00`:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_hour1">
  <input type="text" id="hour_from" name="hour_from" class="form-control" value="2017-12-24 13:00" />
</div>
```

```js
$('#datetimepicker_hour1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'es',
  format: 'hh:ii',
  minuteStep: 60,
  autoclose: true,
  minView: 1,
  maxView: 1,
  startView: 1
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the console error did you get when you've place the [value] as a [time format] instead of a [fulldate]?

Comment: could you check this fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/pps04unz/]. I find it okay when just putting `value="13:00"`. shouldn't it be all you want ? what exactly the error ?.

Comment: Yes, the error when I put the value as time like `value="13:00"` is: `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?ver=4.8.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined`

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I can see the same error en the jsfiddle example you are shared :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a little trick. First we'll hide the input field. Then we'll devide the datetime value by space character to get only the time and set this as the input value. After that we will show the input field.

```js
var $hour_from = $("#hour_from");
$hour_from.datetimepicker({
  language: 'es',
  format: 'hh:ii',
  minuteStep: 60,
  autoclose: true,
  minView: 1,
  maxView: 1,
  startView: 1,
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm',

});
$hour_from.val($hour_from.val().split(' ')[1])
$hour_from.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_hour1">
  <input type="text" id="hour_from" name="hour_from" class="form-control" value="2017-12-24 13:00" data-date-format="hh:ii" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I have not been able to answer before. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

And few years later I had a similar problem, and solved it with data attribute like this.

Lets take all the code posted in the question (second part, where you added value).

I added few data attributes to the input, data-date and data-inputvalue and have left the actual value empty.

```
    <input type="text" id="hour_from" name="hour_from" class="form-control" data-date="2017-12-24 13:00" data-inputvalue="13:00" value="" />
```

Now let's init the date picker just like in posted question, and add three rows below.

```
//init
$('#datetimepicker_hour1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'es',
  format: 'hh:ii',
  minuteStep: 60,
  autoclose: true,
  minView: 1,
  maxView: 1,
  startView: 1
});

//taking data attr and storing it to value
var inputvalue = $('#hour_from').data('inputvalue');
$('#hour_from').val(inputvalue);

//informing datepicker the value changed (will work without this)
$('#datetimepicker_hour1').datetimepicker('update');
```

Here is the whole example in a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh15szre/5/).

Hope this helps someone ;D

Comment: Works like a charm!!!!!! Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks comrad!

Answer (score -1):

Set the value in the inputfield after `datetimepicker` has been initialized, then everything works.

```
var hour_from = "13:00";

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker_hour1">
  <input type="text" id="hour_from" name="hour_from" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>

$('#datetimepicker_hour1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'es',
  format: 'hh:ii',
  minuteStep: 60,
  autoclose: true,
  minView: 1,
  maxView: 1,
  startView: 1
});

$('#hour_from').val(hour_from);
```